# What is the syntax for defining a return type depending on a parameter value?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have a method `query` that accepts parameters:

- `sql` the SQL string
- `qrm` (query result mask, e.g. `one`, `many`, etc) defines the expected result format.

```
const query = (sql: string, qrm: 'one' | 'many') => {
  if (qrm === 'one') {
    return {
      id: 1
    };
  } else {
    return [
      {
        id: 1
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

The result can be either `Object` or `Array<Object>`.

How do I change the function return type depending on the parameter value?